# Create sections and shortcuts in them for an application in start menu

Tags: winapi, shortcut

I want programmatically add file shortcuts into application menu (in start menu) which opens by pressing ">" button on application. I dont know how it is called.
For example, in google chrome's such menu created sections and shortcuts in them.
http://s1.postimg.org/wj433nxsf/image.png
How do it in Win32 API?

**EDIT**: It seems that it will be available in JDK 9. Here is the quote from [JEP 272](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/272):

> - Action shortcuts: Provide action shortcuts that are accessible by a pop-up menu, for example, Windows jump-lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right-click on an application in the Taskbar or click the ">" button in the Start menu, Windows displays a [**Jump List**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#jump_lists).

As described in the linked article, if your application is registered to handle certain file types then the Shell will automatically build the list of recently used files as users open them from Explorer.  You don't need to do anything.

If you need to further customize the list, the article explains how.